# Touchpad and Wheel on event.wheelDelta

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I recently encountered a problem trying to make a div's content horizontaly scrollable, smooth. I achieved the result I want when using a touchpad, sadly its diffrent with a mouse scrollwheel. To get the scroll intensity I use "event.wheelDelta". When logging this to the console and using a touchpad to scroll to the right I will get numbers indicating the intensity, which looks similar to this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 45, 150, 50, 30, 15, 13, 4, 3, 2, 1... But when I use a scrollwheel on a mouse to scroll it looks like this: 150, 150, 150, 150, 150... That in the end causes a non smooth scrolling behavior when using the scrollwheel on a mouse. Here is a good example of the issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event. Can someone help me with this? Below you see the logic of the function I use. The function gets called on a wheel event in Vue.js (`v-on:wheel="replaceScrollDirection($event)"`).

```
replaceScrollDirection() {
            event.preventDefault()
            this.scrollPosition = document.getElementById("holideWrapper").scrollLeft
            this.scrollIntensity = event.wheelDelta
            this.scroll = this.scrollPosition + this.scrollIntensity * -1
            document.getElementById("holideWrapper").scrollTo({left: this.scroll})
}
```